# Run different code after each test function

Tags: scala, playframework

I am writing tests that interact with a database, and would like to do some sort of setup and teardown that is specific to each test.  This is what I currently have:

```
"my test" in {

    // Use anorm to populate the database
    Db.withConnection { 

        SQL"INSERT INTO ...".execute()

        // Do some tests
        foo must equal 1
        bar must equal 2

        // Remove the test data
        SQL"DELETE FROM ...".execute()
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that if one of the tests fail, then the execution is halted and the test data never gets removed from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@marcospereira's answer works well if you're using `specs2` for testing, but I am using the `PlaySpec`.  The following example:

1. Inserts a row into a db,
2. Sets the `rowID` so it can be used everywhere else,
3. Makes a GET request to the server which is dependant on the `rowID`,
4. Tests the results,
5. Removes the corresponding row from the database.

   ```
   import anorm._
   import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfter, DoNotDiscover}
   import org.scalatestplus.play.{ConfiguredServer, PlaySpec}
   import play.api.db.DB
   import play.api.libs.json.Json
   import play.api.libs.ws.WS
   import play.api.test.Helpers._

   @DoNotDiscover
   class ExampleSpec extends PlaySpec with BeforeAndAfter with ConfiguredServer {

       val baseAddress =  s"http://localhost:$testServerPort/"
       var rowID: Int = _

       before {
           DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
               rowID = SQL"INSERT INTO some_table (col1, col2) VALUES('v1', 'v2')".executeInsert(SqlParser.scalar[Int].single)
           }
       }

       after {
           DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
               SQL"DELETE FROM some_table WHERE id = $rowID".execute()
           }
       }

       "GET my/endpoint/{id}" should {

           "return a 200" in {
               val address = baseAddress + s"my/endpoint/$rowID"

               val response = await(WS.url(address).get())
               response.status mustEqual OK
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using specs2, you can create an `Around` scope for each test:

```
"my test" in DatabaseSetup {
  // Do some tests
  foo must equal 1
  bar must equal 2
}

trait DatabaseSetup extends org.specs2.mutable.Around {
  def around[T: org.specs2.execute.AsResult](t: => T) = {

    Db.withConnection {
      // Insert data
    }

    val result = org.specs2.execute.AsResult(t)

    Db.withConnection {
      // Remove data
    }

    result
  }
}
```

Anyway, this could be very hard to maintain and such structure is probably revealing some problem with your production code or with your test code. You should ask yourself why you can't reuse the database setup.

Comment: My application is a REST API, so I just want to test the endpoints by putting some data in the database, then hitting the endpoint (I know what to expect because I just put data in), and then removing that data so I don't pollute any other tests.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Well, if the test is focused on one resource, I don't see why would you need a different setup for each test "method". I mean, if you have `PersonApiSpec`, `CountryApiSpec`, `LessonApiSpec`, etc, I think this will give you enough isolation. Of course, this opinion is based on what I can infer from the question. :-)

Comment: Anyway, the around trait in my answer can be used for both cases.